# Dropdown in React using bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4

When I click on a single dropdown menu link in the navigation bar, all the dropdown menu links also show or display. How do I fix this by letting only one dropdown menu link show?

I have tried changing the id value that points to aria-labelledby

This is the state of my app

```
      state = {
        dropDown: false
      };


      handleDropdown = e => {
            this.setState({ dropDown: !this.state.dropDown });
        };
```

Inside the render function

```
      render() {
        const { dropDown } = this.state;

      /*Conditional statement to select a class base on the state*/

      const dropMenu = dropDown ? 'dropdown-menu show' : 'dropdown-menu';

      /*The two dropdown menu list the displays(both) even when one is clicked*/

    <li className="nav-item dropdown">
                      <Link
                        onClick={this.handleDropdown}
                        className="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
                        href="#"
                        id="navbarDropdown"
                        role="button"
                        data-toggle="dropdown"
                        aria-haspopup="true"
                        aria-expanded="false"
                      >
                        Dropdown
                      </Link>
                      <div className={dropMenu} aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <Link className="dropdown-item" to="#">
                          Action
                        </Link>
                        <Link className="dropdown-item" to="#">
                          Another action
                        </Link>
                        <div className="dropdown-divider" />
                        <Link className="dropdown-item" to="#">
                          Something else here
                        </Link>
                      </div>
                    </li>

    <li className="nav-item dropdown">
                      <Link
                        onClick={this.handleDropdown}
                        className="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
                        href="#"
                        id="navbarDropdown"
                        role="button"
                        data-toggle="dropdown"
                        aria-haspopup="true"
                        aria-expanded="false"
                      >
                        Dropdown
                      </Link>
                      <div className={dropMenu} aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <Link className="dropdown-item" to="#">
                          Action
                        </Link>
                        <Link className="dropdown-item" to="#">
                          Another action
                        </Link>
                        <div className="dropdown-divider" />
                        <Link className="dropdown-item" to="#">
                          Something else here
                        </Link>
                      </div>
                    </li>
      };
```

Comment: Just as an alternative to you hand writing this, you should make use of someone else's code. https://reactstrap.github.io/components/navs/ This has all the Bootstrap 4 menu's pre-existing.

Comment: Thanks for the resource. But in this project, I want to use Bootstrap as a dependency rather than using a Bootstrap package like *react-bootstrap*

Answer (score 1):

**Updated code**

Change the state variable as follows:

```
state = {
  dropDownState: [false, false]
};
```

As you have just have two `li > div` the array contains two elements, if menu items increase, increase them as well.

Then the div's would look like

`<div className={dropMenu[0]} aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">` and
`<div className={dropMenu[1]} aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">`

Each of the function bindings would look like

```
onClick={() => this.handleDropdown(0)}
onClick={() => this.handleDropdown(1)}
```

The actual function would then change to

```
handleDropdown = (menuIndex) => {
   let newMenuState = this.state.dropDownState.map((val, index) => {
       if(index === menuIndex) {
           return !val
       } else return val
   });

  this.setState({ dropDownState: newMenuState })
};
```

Please note I haven't run the code on my end, but you should get the idea.

**Old Answer**

Instead of calling the function, bind the value to the function:

Change

`onClick={this.handleDropdown}`

To

`onClick={() => this.handleDropdown()}`

Comment: I tried binding the method, but it still called the two dropdown menu links

Comment: Where are you using the const `const dropMenu`? I don't see it in your code anywhere else. Don't you need to use that as the class of the div inside each `li`? Not only that, a single state variable decides the class which then affects all the divs inside each `li`s (after applying the const as the class for the div). You need to make it dynamic using array. Each array element would hold the state for each `li > div`.

Comment: Ouch, sorry. I just edited the code. Exactly, I used the dropMenu on the div inside the li and the problem still exists. Please, I don't get the path where I need to make it dynamic. Because **const dropMenu** holds the class depending on the state of dropDown in the **render function**. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I'm getting close to the solution. I console.log(dropMenu[0]) which you used in the div element in your updated code and got the first letter of the class which was **d** (ie. dropdown-menu).

Comment: Change `<div className={dropMenu[0]} aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">` to `<div className={this.state.dropDownState[0]} aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">`, sorry I missed that part. Basically use the array element from the new state variable.

Comment: ```this.state.dropDownState[0]``` used in className will return a boolean and not a class. So i will rather end up with something like this ```className={true}```  inside the div.

Comment: You could improvise that code a bit. Create local variables based on those values and then assign appropriate classes to them, add something like this inside the render block:
`const classLi1 = this.state.dropDownState[0] ? 'dropdown-menu show' : 'dropdown-menu';`
`const classLi2 = this.state.dropDownState[1] ? 'dropdown-menu show' : 'dropdown-menu';`
and then apply those vars in the div as classname.
`<div className={classLi1} aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">`

Answer (score 1):

because you only 1 state to handle show and hide the dropdown menu. try doing it like this :

```
state = {
  dropDown: {
    link1: false,
    link2: false,
  }
}

handleDropdown = e => {
  const { id } = e.target;

  this.setState(prevState => ({
    dropDown : {
      ...prevState.dropDown,
      [id]: !prevState.dropDown[id],
    }
  }));
}

render() {

const { dropDown } = this.state;

      /*Conditional statement to select a class base on the state*/

      const dropMenu = dropDown ? 'dropdown-menu show' : 'dropdown-menu';

      /*The two dropdown menu list the displays(both) even when one is clicked*/

    <li className="nav-item dropdown">
                      <Link
                        onClick={this.handleDropdown}
                        className="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
                        href="#"
                        id="link1" // name your id same as the variable from state dropDown
                        role="button"
                        data-toggle="dropdown"
                        aria-haspopup="true"
                        aria-expanded="false"
                      >
                        Dropdown
                      </Link>
                      <div className={`dropdown-menu ${dropDown.link1 ? 'show' : ''}`} aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <Link className="dropdown-item" to="#">
                          Action
                        </Link>
                        <Link className="dropdown-item" to="#">
                          Another action
                        </Link>
                        <div className="dropdown-divider" />
                        <Link className="dropdown-item" to="#">
                          Something else here
                        </Link>
                      </div>
                    </li>

    <li className="nav-item dropdown">
                      <Link
                        onClick={this.handleDropdown}
                        className="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
                        href="#"
                        id="link2" // name your id same as the variable from state dropDown
                        role="button"
                        data-toggle="dropdown"
                        aria-haspopup="true"
                        aria-expanded="false"
                      >
                        Dropdown
                      </Link>
                      <div className={`dropdown-menu ${dropDown.link2 ? 'show' : ''}`} aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <Link className="dropdown-item" to="#">
                          Action
                        </Link>
                        <Link className="dropdown-item" to="#">
                          Another action
                        </Link>
                        <div className="dropdown-divider" />
                        <Link className="dropdown-item" to="#">
                          Something else here
                        </Link>
                      </div>
                    </li>
}
```

hope it works.